Can "comprehensive reading" mean "extensive reading"?
"Comprehensive" means full coverage, and here are some real-life examples:

In addition, a comprehensive vocabulary is a potent tool for communication--finding just the right word to express your thoughts is an extremely useful weapon in your educational arsenal.

Source: Why Having an Educated Vocabulary Is an Important Asset

A comprehensive list of all activities takes the guesswork out of site management, debugging, and repair.

Source: Activity Log
A complete record of everything that happens on your site.
However, comprehensive reading primarily means reading with comprehension rather than "extensive reading".

Source: Google search results
I am wondering if "comprehensive reading" can mean "extensive reading"? Or "extensive vocabulary" mean "comprehensive vocabulary"?

I don't think comprehensive reading (reading an extensive range / many / varied texts) should ever be used with allusions to "reading comprehension" (understanding what one is reading). Equally, comprehensive vocabulary should only ever be used to refer to the number of words a person uses, not their understanding of those words. For almost all purposes, comprehension and comprehensive should be kept widely separated.

Comprehension is the faculty by which you obtain knowledge. Comprehensive describes a condition in which you have a full knowledge or a general understanding of a subject. See Are comprehensiveness and comprehension completely unrelated words?, which probably wouldn't have been closed if it had been asked on ELL rather than ELU.

comprehensive vocabulary ain't great. This all sounds like editing to me.

Comprehensive has these two different meanings. So you should take care about what meaning is meant; often it will be clear from context.

@FumbleFingers I've updated my question, please take a look. Thanks.

Please think three times before even reading, never mind trusting, anything whose title includes '… an Educated Vocabulary…'

'Comprehensive' and 'extensive' are not interchangeable.
'Comprehensive' can include 'extensive'.
'Extensive' can not include 'Comprehensive'

"Comprehensive reading" does not mean "Reading and understanding" it means reading that fully covers a topic.

Comprehensive reading of the relevant papers is necessary for success in a PhD.

"Reading comprehension" is about understanding.

Children do reading comprehension exercises as part of elementary school lessons.

You may find examples of "comprehensive" relating to understanding in very old texts, not usually in modern texts.  Oxford Languages calls that sense "archaic".

As well as the point that James K raises in his answer, "comprehensive" does not mean the same as "extensive".

comprehensive: complete and including everything that is necessary


extensive: covering a large area; having a great range

"Extensive" reading can cover a large area but not be complete, in which case it is not comprehensive.

OED: comprehensive - Characterized by comprehension; having the attribute of comprising or including much; of large content or scope. Looks pretty much like "extensive" to me.

+1.  Some people use words loosely. Some precisely.  That definition admits the looser usage.  A person with knowledge of both the precise and sloppy uses of the word "comprehensive" would not have  said "a comprehensive vocabulary" but "an extensive vocabulary".
